# Could multiplication be defined as $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ..A_n|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

Taking discrete math which suddenly right now I am thinking of what dividing and multiplication do when it comes to what I learned in this class. But would multiplication be defined as the cardinality of a union of a set and itself? Not sure how to word this properly.

Comment: I cannot understand your question.

Comment: Yea I probably worded it terribly.
I am just thinking about math generally.. 
I was thinking of how dividing could be described as diving something into sets of what your dividing by. So I was wondering how I could maybe express multiplication with sets but I'm not sure if it makes any sense. lol

Comment: Multiplying the cardinalities is achieved with the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is a set such that |A| = m, then you can take the cartesian product of A with itself $n$ times to get $m^n$.
$$|A\times A\times...\times A| = |\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) : a_j \in A \}| = |A|^n = m^n.$$
If you wanted to get a set of size $mn$, you can take the disjoint union of $A$ with itself $n$ times $$|\cup_{i=1}^n \cup_{j=1}^m \{(i,a_j)\}| = nm $$

Comment: Ah that is so cool

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you very much for pointing that out!